# Footer right side not aligning

Tags: html, css, html-lists, footer

I have been trying to get my inline footer to align with the div above it on the right side of the page. It aligns properly on the left but not the right side. I need this to be able to remain aligned while also changing the screen size. I have created a JSFiddle for it. https://jsfiddle.net/3ymr09b7/1/. I believe it has something to do with

```
li.right{
  float:right;
}
```

but I am not sure what to add since everything I have tried has broken. Do I add something to the ul? Could I please get some advice or a location to read more?

Comment: It seems to work? Except for when the screen is too small of course and then it moves to the next line.

Comment: It definitely does not work, it extends too far to the right touching the edge of the screen instead of ending just before.

Comment: Remove the padding or the width from ul, otherwise you are essentially telling it to be "100% + 4px" so it will be 4 pixels wider than its parent. Doesn't have anything to do with floats though.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean or how to do that. I have tried a few attempts at it and still don't get it. I have changed my width tag to 100%-4px, and it broke that section and another section on the site that was unconnected.

Comment: The issue is that it is wider than it should be so I don't see how adding 4p will help it be shorter.

Comment: You might need to read up on the css box model. Unless you are using the alternative box model (box-sizing: border-box) padding will be added to the width. For example if your width is set to 100% and you have 2px of padding on either side the total width will be 100% + 4px which of course is going to be more than 100% which is why it is bigger. As I said you need to "remove the padding or the width from ul", I didn't say "set the width to 100% + 4px".

Comment: When I do that it is no longer aligned on the left side or the right side. I need it to be 2.5 px in from the left and 2.5 px in from the right. Not the full width.